# Rails uses wrong class in belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an application managing software tests and a class called TestResult:

```
class TestResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_case,   :class_name => "TestCase"
end
```

I'm right now migrating from Rails 1.x to 2.3.5.

In Rails 1.x everything works fine.

When trying to access the association in Rails 2.3.5, I get the following error:

NoMethodError: undefined method 'find' for ActiveRecord::TestCase:Class
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:49:in 'send'

from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:49:in 'find_target'

from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:239:in 'load_target'

from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:112:in 'reload'

from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1250:in 'test_case'

My Question is: how can I tell Rails to use my TestCase-class instead of ActiveRecord::TestCase.

TestCase class:

```
class TestCase < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_table_name "test_case"

  has_many   :test_results
  belongs_to :component,         :foreign_key => "subsystem_id"
  belongs_to :domain,            :foreign_key => "area_id"
  belongs_to :use_case,          :foreign_key => "use_case_id"
end
```

Comment: why are you migrating to rail 2.3.5? current version is 2.3.8? And if you already do the work, I would try to migrate to rails 3.0, because it is due soon

Comment: I believe if ruby is looking for `ActiveRecord::TestCase` it didn't found `TestCase`. Can you post some more code? the TestCase Class?

Comment: why 2.3.5? well, just started migrating like two month ago and forgot to update rails meanwhile. did the upgrade right now, but does not solve this problem. As there seems to be no rails 3 release date and we have to finish migration due to end of june, the time is just too short...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
class TestResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_case, :class_name => "::TestCase"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
class TestResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_case
end
```